# How to get specific value from ajax response

Tags: jquery

The below code is response of ajax call in my implementation. 
  `/* response of ajax call */
 <script> var count = 6; </script>
 <div> some code goes here</div>`

how to get the above count value from ajax response in jquery

```
   $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "text",
        timeout: 20000,
        success: function(response){  },
        error: function(){/* error code goes here*/}
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the way how your server sends Ajax responses, for example using JSON:

```js
{
    "data": {
        "count": 6
    },
    "html": "<div>some code goes here</div>"
}
```

Then access the counter using this script:

```js
$.getJSON({
    url: url,
    timeout: 20000,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response.data.count);
    },
    error: function() {/* error code goes here*/}
});
```

Comment: thank you J.M for your response. response comes as a html and it contains script tag which has count value, need to access that count value and ajax dataType is text.

Comment: You cannot change the response type?

Answer (score 0):

If you must accept the return value in mentioned string form and distill the count value from it, then RegExp saves the day:

```
var COUNT_DIGIT_EXPRESSION = /count\s?=\s(\d+);/i;

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "text",
  timeout: 20000,
  success: function(response){
    var countMatch = response.responseText.match(COUNT_DIGIT_EXPRESSION);
    var countInt;

    // Return val from match is array with second element being the matched
    // capturing subgroup (\d+), which is the digit or digits themselves.
    if (countMatch && countMatch.length == 2) {
      countInt = parseInt(countMatch[1], 10);
    }
    console.log('Count value is ' + countInt);
  },
  error: function(){/* error code goes here*/}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With the entire text of your response being:

```
<script> var count = 6; </script> <div> some code goes here</div>
```

Use this code to get the result between specified tags:

```
var resultmatch = xmlHttpReq.responseText.match(/<script>(.*?)<\/script>/);
```

If you then had:

```
echo resultmatch;
```

It would output:

```
var count = 6;
```

= = =

But since you want the value of count, do it with a single statement as such:

```
eval(xmlHttpReq.responseText.match(/<script>(.*?)<\/script>/));
```

This will cause to display in your html page the JavaScript, **var count = 6;** as if it had been typed as code. So now that you have a variable named **count** with a value, you can use it as you please.

If you then did:

```
echo count;
```

It would output:

```
6
```

And of course you can use the variable **count** in your continuing JavaScript to use its value.